# jQuery UI Dialog IE8 problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI dialog which contains a form, allowing the user to post an ad. Since the form contains a file upload, the form's target is an iFrame.

From this iFrame, I destroy the dialog in the parent window and create a new one (or I change the options of the original dialog, it doesn't make any difference). The point is that from the iFrame, I define new buttons for the new dialog which themselves are attached to events that work on the main window elements.

In Firefox, Safari, Chrome this works perfectly well:

```
var p = parent;    

p.$('#dialog_new_ad').html('<form id="post_ad_form" style="display: none" data-remote="true"></form><div class="header"><h1 class="header_title"></h1><div class="header_company"></div><div class="header_location"></div></div><div class="content"></div>');

p.$('#dialog_new_ad').dialog({
 minHeight: 600,
 width: 800,
 position: ['center',25],
 modal: true,
 autoOpen: false,
 title: '<%= 'Preview: ' if params[:action] == 'preview' %><%= @ad.title %>',
 buttons: {
  "« Back": function() {
   p.$('#post_ad_form').attr('method','get');
   p.$('#post_ad_form').attr('action','/ads/<%= @ad.id %>/revise');
   p.$('#post_ad_form').submit();
  },
  "Submit »": function() {
   p.$('#post_ad_form').attr('method','post');
   p.$('#post_ad_form').html('<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">');
   p.$('#post_ad_form').attr('action',"/ads/<%= @ad.id %>/confirm");
   p.$('#post_ad_form').submit();
  }
 }
});
```

This code is in the iFrame which the form POSTs to.

If you look at the button functions, you'll see that what they are doing is also defined in the context of the child window (iFrame), even though the buttons are in the parent window. It's because the function is created in the iFrame, and thus the objects must be referenced from that context.

Now the problem is that in Internet Explorer it works sometimes, but not others. When it doesn't, the error I get is "Can't execute code in a freed script" and it points to the part of jquery-ui.js where the button functions are defined. Whether or not the error occurs is simply random. As if it depends on whether or not something has finished before that code is called. As mentioned, in any other browser it always works.

The entire thing (in the iFrame) is enclosed in a `$(function() { [...] }` , so the DOM is loaded that's not the issue. It might have something to do with the fact that the form which is created by the .html call is not "finished being put into the DOM" when the button functions are defined, but that would seem strange to me. Any ideas?

**Note:** The jQuery .html function uses innerHTML to create the new elements. Is it possible that this leads to any problems in IE, if the elements are referenced directly thereafter?

**Update:** I gave up and simply put the dummy form in the parent element, so it can always be used by children iFrames of different kinds, whether or not they are actually loaded. When the form is a static part of the parent HTML and not dynamically inserted, everything works just fine. I still don't understand why the dynamic insertion doesn't work in IE though.